# JQuery UI Resizable not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, drupal, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm working on a site in Drupal 6 using JQuery Update and Jquery UI modules.

I have a resizable `<div>` tag with only an East handle and with a set minimum and maximum width.  It work's perfectly in FireFox and Chrome but not in IE (I'm using 9).

In IE the resizing element loads and is displayed properly but the element will not resize. Here's the weird thing, if I tell IE to render the page in quirks mode the page breaks (and bad) but the resizing element works properly.

```
$('.feature-clean').resizable({ maxHeight:348, minHeight:348, minWidth:100, maxWidth:1100, handles:'e' });
```

Here's a link to the page where you can see the resizable element http://spadent.baglerit.com/how

Has anyone else run into this and have found a solution?

Thanks

Update: 
It's actually an issue with a line of javascript that was designed to make the resize work properly in IE <9 that caused it to break in IE 9 and 10.  I know it's not a the best solution, but removing the line of code worked.

Comment: You may get more answers if you post some of your HTML and more of your JS.

Comment: That's the only JS I'm using that does the resizing.  As for the HTML it's a block in the page so there's alot there and it's mostly generated by the CMS, a link to the site is propably easier.  You can see the slider at http://spadent.baglerit.com/how

Answer (score 0):

I examined your HTML in Chrome debugger, but I don't see script tags pointing to jQuery UI referenced on the page.

The `resizable()` call you are making won't work without it, since it is defined in jQuery UI.